# .NET 6.0 Visual Studio 2022 Aws Lambda Function

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Good evening, I am trying to deploy my API to Lambda Function, my project is developed in .NET 6 (C#), when doing the deploy it does it correctly, but when trying to access the APIS it throws me:

{"message": "Internal server error"}

Here is my code:

serverless.template:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Transform" : "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description" : "Starting template for an AWS Serverless Application.",
  "Parameters" : {
  },
  "Resources" : {
    "DefaultFunction" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "RtvcApi::RtvcApi.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnet6",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "Description": "Default function",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [ "AWSLambda_FullAccess" ],
        "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs" : {
    "ApiURL" : {
        "Description" : "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
        "Value" : { "Fn::Sub" : "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/" }
    }
  }
}
```

aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json

```
{
    "Information" : [
        "This file provides default values for the deployment wizard inside Visual Studio and the AWS Lambda commands added to the .NET Core CLI.",
        "To learn more about the Lambda commands with the .NET Core CLI execute the following command at the command line in the project root directory.",
        "dotnet lambda help",
        "All the command line options for the Lambda command can be specified in this file."
    ],
    "profile"     : "StoreSysAWS",
    "region"      : "us-east-1",
    "configuration" : "Release",
    "function-runtime" : "dotnet6",
    "framework"        : "net6.0",
    "template"         : "serverless.template",
    "template-parameters" : "",
    "s3-prefix"           : "CoreAPI/",
    "s3-bucket"           : "rtvapibucket",
    "stack-name"          : "CoreAPIStack"
}
```

LambdaEntryPoint.cs:

```
using Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer;

namespace RtvcApi;

public class LambdaEntryPoint : APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Program>()
            .UseLambdaServer();
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using CleanArchitecture.Identity;
using Infrastructure.EntityFramework;
using RtvcApi;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        var app = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        app.Run();

    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .Build();

        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
            webBuilder =>
            webBuilder
            .UseStartup<Startup>())
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddControllers();
                services.AddApplicationServices();
                services.AddAuthentication();
                services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                    builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    );
                });
                services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
                services.AddSwaggerGen();
                services.AddInfrastructureServices(configuration);
                services.ConfigureAuthenticationServices(configuration);
                services.AddAuthorization();
            });
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using RtvcApi.Middlewares;

namespace RtvcApi;

public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) 
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapGet("/test", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("va...");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I was trying several ways to do it but I don't know why it doesn't work for me.

Example of tests I did:

https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2022/10/simple-dependency-injection-for-net-lambda-functions/

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/discussions/1370

https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2022/01/net-6-web-api-in-a-container-in-a-lambda/

https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/introducing-the-net-6-runtime-for-aws-lambda/

Comment: In cloudwatch my lambda function throws the following error:

---> System.InvalidOperationException: A public method named 'ConfigureProduction' or 'Configure' could not be found in the 'Program' type.